# Try to do methods C#

Tags: c#

I can try to do method for change length of array.

But newArray not visible in main...

What can i do for?

I am a begginer and need some help

```
    internal class Program
    {
        static int[] Addstart(ref int[] oldArray, int element)
        {
            int[] newArray = new int[oldArray.Length + 1];
            newArray[0] = element;
            for (int i = 1; i < newArray.Length; i++)
            {
                newArray[i] = oldArray[i - 1];
            }
            return newArray;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] oldArray = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
            
            Addstart(ref oldArray, 8);
            for(int i = 0; i < newArray.Length; i++)
                Console.WriteLine(newArray[i] + " ");

            Console.ReadKey();


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You missed a closing curly brace behind `return newArray;`.

Comment: Hint: you're not using the value returned by `Addstart`... maybe change your Main method to have `int[] newArray = Addstart(ref oldArray, 8);`. It's unclear why you're using `ref`, admittedly, given that you're not assigning `oldArray` a new value in `Addstart` anyway. (I'd also strongly encourage you to start following .NET naming conventions as early as possible, so something like `AddStart` instead of `Addstart`.)

Comment: As an aside, if you want a collection that can grow, you might be better off using a List (or possibly an ArrayList). `List<int> intArray = new List<int>();`

Comment: always chose List<T> over an array. Never use an ArrayList!

Answer (score 0):

When you want to use the [`ref` approach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref) to change the value of a variable on the caller side, you assign the new value inside the method `Addstart()` instead of using the `return` statement. The method can look like this:

```
static void Addstart(ref int[] oldArray, int element)
{
    int[] newArray = new int[oldArray.Length + 1];
    newArray[0] = element;
    for (int i = 1; i < newArray.Length; i++)
    {
        newArray[i] = oldArray[i - 1];
    }
    oldArray = newArray; // <-- set new value for ref parameter 'oldArray'
}
```

After that you call your `Addstart()` method and use the variable `oldArray` in your `Main()` method.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] oldArray = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
     
    Addstart(ref oldArray, 8);
    for(int i = 0; i < oldArray.Length; i++)
        Console.WriteLine(oldArray[i] + " ");
}
```

This will generate the following output:

```
8 
1 
2 
3 
4 
5 
6 
7
```